# Abstract not on a separate page

Tags: page-breaking, titles, koma-script, abstract

I'm writing a scientific paper for my university. The page after my table of contents I would like to start my document with a abstract, directly following with the first section. As far as I know, the  document class `scrartcl` will not insert page breaks after the abstract. Somehow my abstract is on an own page. 
Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
    12pt,
    titlepage,
    twoside, 
    abstracton,
    ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\newtheorem{bsp}{Beispiel}

\graphicspath{{Grafiken/}} 
\usepackage{everyshi}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm} 
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock}{150}(32,155)
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{Huge}
\textbf{\textsf{blabla} }
\end{Huge}
\vspace{1cm}

\hspace{1.25cm}\Large{\textsf{...}}
\hspace{1.25cm}\Large{\textsf{bla}}
\vspace{1cm}
\hspace{1.25cm}\Large{\textsf{bla}}

%Autor
\hspace{1.25cm}\Large{\textsf{...}}

\vspace{3.5cm}
\hspace{1.25cm}\Large{\textsf{\today}}
\end{textblock}

\end{titlepage}
\null\newpage

\linespread{1.25} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}{right}{top}{bottom}{headheight}{headsep}{footheight}{footskip}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\tableofcontents % Inhaltsverzeichnis
\newpage

\begin{abstract}
Abstract\dots blablablablablablablablablablablablablabla blablablablabla    blablabl ablablablablabla blablablabla blablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
\end{abstract}
\section{Einleitung}
(...)
\end{document}
```

What's the cause?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `titlepage` class option, a page break will also be added after the `abstract` environment (like it would when using the `article` standard class). Solution: Either don't use this option at all, or disable it before the abstract using `\KOMAoptions{titlepage=false}`.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\author{(Author}
\title{(Title)}

\maketitle

\KOMAoptions{titlepage=false}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{foo}

\lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! This works out perfectly.